# Add to cart product with selected checkbox price in Php

Tags: php, shopping-cart

Hi friend's I have a small project in PHP for Shopping cart and my problem is that: I have one product with two different prices checkboxes (Price 1 = 60 USD AND Price 2 = 20 USD), and i don't know how to make'it work to add to cart the product with the selected checkbox prices to be funnctional. Check image with the product. [See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T953l.png). Note that in mysql db in product table i have price and price2. Any help appreciated!

Index Php code:

```
<?php 
// Initialize shopping cart class 
include_once 'Cart.class.php'; 
$cart = new Cart; 
// Include configuration file 
include_once 'config.php'; 

// Include database connection file 
include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 
?>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="../assets/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <div class="cart-view">
        <a href="viewCart.php" title="View Cart"><i class="icart"></i> (<?php echo ($cart->total_items() > 0)?$cart->total_items().' Items':'Gol'; ?>)</a>
    </div>
  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="our-best-courses best-courses-list  ">
              <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">

    <?php 
        // Fetch products from the database 
        $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1"); 
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){ 
    ?>
                     <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="courses-box">
                            <div class="courses-img img_hover_effect"><img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="Oana Ionita"></div>
                            <div class="courses-cnt">
                                <div class="text-center courses-name"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></div>
                                 <p class="categorie text-center"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>
                              <ul class="color-info clearfix list-unstyled ">
                                <li>
                                 <div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-living-coral-filled  ">
                                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" id="individual">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="individual">Individual:</label>
                                      <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $row['price']; ?> <?php echo PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?> / Hour</span>
                                 </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                  <div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-living-coral-filled  ">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" id="grup">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="grup">Group:</label>
                                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $row['pricet']; ?> <?php echo PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?> / Hour</span>
                                 </div>
                             </li>
                               </ul>

                    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                     <center> <a href="cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-round displayblock">Add to cart</a></center>
                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
      <?php } ?>
   </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Cart.class Php:

```
<?php 
// Start session 
if(!session_id()){ 
    session_start(); 
} 

/** 
 * Shopping Cart Class 
 * 
 * @package        PHP Library 
 * @category    Shopping Cart 
 * @author        CodexWorld Dev Team 
 * @link        https://www.codexworld.com 
 */ 
class Cart { 
    protected $cart_contents = array(); 

    public function __construct(){ 
        // get the shopping cart array from the session 
        $this->cart_contents = !empty($_SESSION['cart_contents'])?$_SESSION['cart_contents']:NULL; 
        if ($this->cart_contents === NULL){ 
            // set some base values 
            $this->cart_contents = array('cart_total' => 0, 'total_items' => 0); 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Cart Contents: Returns the entire cart array 
     * @param    bool 
     * @return    array 
     */ 
    public function contents(){ 
        // rearrange the newest first 
        $cart = array_reverse($this->cart_contents); 

        // remove these so they don't create a problem when showing the cart table 
        unset($cart['total_items']); 
        unset($cart['cart_total']); 

        return $cart; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Get cart item: Returns a specific cart item details 
     * @param    string    $row_id 
     * @return    array 
     */ 
    public function get_item($row_id){ 
        return (in_array($row_id, array('total_items', 'cart_total'), TRUE) OR ! isset($this->cart_contents[$row_id])) 
            ? FALSE 
            : $this->cart_contents[$row_id]; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Total Items: Returns the total item count 
     * @return    int 
     */ 
    public function total_items(){ 
        return $this->cart_contents['total_items']; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Cart Total: Returns the total price 
     * @return    int 
     */ 
    public function total(){ 
        return $this->cart_contents['cart_total']; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Insert items into the cart and save it to the session 
     * @param    array 
     * @return    bool 
     */ 
    public function insert($item = array()){ 
        if(!is_array($item) OR count($item) === 0){ 
            return FALSE; 
        }else{ 
            if(!isset($item['id'], $item['name'], $item['price'], $item['qty'])){ 
                return FALSE; 
            }else{ 
                /* 
                 * Insert Item 
                 */ 
                // prep the quantity 
                $item['qty'] = (float) $item['qty']; 
                if($item['qty'] == 0){ 
                    return FALSE; 
                } 
                // prep the price 
                $item['price'] = (float) $item['price']; 
                // create a unique identifier for the item being inserted into the cart 
                $rowid = md5($item['id']); 
                // get quantity if it's already there and add it on 
                $old_qty = isset($this->cart_contents[$rowid]['qty']) ? (int) $this->cart_contents[$rowid]['qty'] : 0; 
                // re-create the entry with unique identifier and updated quantity 
                $item['rowid'] = $rowid; 
                $item['qty'] += $old_qty; 
                $this->cart_contents[$rowid] = $item; 

                // save Cart Item 
                if($this->save_cart()){ 
                    return isset($rowid) ? $rowid : TRUE; 
                }else{ 
                    return FALSE; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Update the cart 
     * @param    array 
     * @return    bool 
     */ 
    public function update($item = array()){ 
        if (!is_array($item) OR count($item) === 0){ 
            return FALSE; 
        }else{ 
            if (!isset($item['rowid'], $this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']])){ 
                return FALSE; 
            }else{ 
                // prep the quantity 
                if(isset($item['qty'])){ 
                    $item['qty'] = (float) $item['qty']; 
                    // remove the item from the cart, if quantity is zero 
                    if ($item['qty'] == 0){ 
                        unset($this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']]); 
                        return TRUE; 
                    } 
                } 

                // find updatable keys 
                $keys = array_intersect(array_keys($this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']]), array_keys($item)); 
                // prep the price 
                if(isset($item['price'])){ 
                    $item['price'] = (float) $item['price']; 
                } 
                // product id & name shouldn't be changed 
                foreach(array_diff($keys, array('id', 'name')) as $key){ 
                    $this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']][$key] = $item[$key]; 
                } 
                // save cart data 
                $this->save_cart(); 
                return TRUE; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Save the cart array to the session 
     * @return    bool 
     */ 
    protected function save_cart(){ 
        $this->cart_contents['total_items'] = $this->cart_contents['cart_total'] = 0; 
        foreach ($this->cart_contents as $key => $val){ 
            // make sure the array contains the proper indexes 
            if(!is_array($val) OR !isset($val['price'], $val['qty'])){ 
                continue; 
            } 

            $this->cart_contents['cart_total'] += ($val['price'] * $val['qty']); 
            $this->cart_contents['total_items'] += $val['qty']; 
            $this->cart_contents[$key]['subtotal'] = ($this->cart_contents[$key]['price'] * $this->cart_contents[$key]['qty']); 
        } 

        // if cart empty, delete it from the session 
        if(count($this->cart_contents) <= 2){ 
            unset($_SESSION['cart_contents']); 
            return FALSE; 
        }else{ 
            $_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents; 
            return TRUE; 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Remove Item: Removes an item from the cart 
     * @param    int 
     * @return    bool 
     */ 
     public function remove($row_id){ 
        // unset & save 
        unset($this->cart_contents[$row_id]); 
        $this->save_cart(); 
        return TRUE; 
     } 

    /** 
     * Destroy the cart: Empties the cart and destroy the session 
     * @return    void 
     */ 
    public function destroy(){ 
        $this->cart_contents = array('cart_total' => 0, 'total_items' => 0); 
        unset($_SESSION['cart_contents']); 
    } 
}
```

CartAction Php:

```
<?php 
// Initialize shopping cart class 
require_once 'Cart.class.php'; 
$cart = new Cart; 

// Include the database config file 
require_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

// Default redirect page 
$redirectLoc = 'index.php'; 

// Process request based on the specified action 
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !empty($_REQUEST['action'])){ 
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'addToCart' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){ 
        $productID = $_REQUEST['id']; 

        // Get product details 
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ".$productID); 
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc(); 
        $itemData = array( 
            'id' => $row['id'], 
            'name' => $row['name'], 
            'price' => $row['price'],
            'pricet' => $row['pricet'],  
            'qty' => 1 
        ); 

        // Insert item to cart 
        $insertItem = $cart->insert($itemData); 

        // Redirect to cart page 
        $redirectLoc = $insertItem?'index.php':'index.php'; 
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'updateCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){ 
        // Update item data in cart 
        $itemData = array( 
            'rowid' => $_REQUEST['id'], 
            'qty' => $_REQUEST['qty'] 
        ); 
        $updateItem = $cart->update($itemData); 

        // Return status 
        echo $updateItem?'ok':'err';die; 
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'removeCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){ 
        // Remove item from cart 
        $deleteItem = $cart->remove($_REQUEST['id']); 

        // Redirect to cart page 
        $redirectLoc = 'viewCart.php'; 
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'placeOrder' && $cart->total_items() > 0){ 
        $redirectLoc = 'checkout.php'; 

        // Store post data 
        $_SESSION['postData'] = $_POST; 

        $first_name = strip_tags($_POST['first_name']); 
        $last_name = strip_tags($_POST['last_name']); 
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']); 
        $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']); 
        $address = strip_tags($_POST['address']); 

        $errorMsg = ''; 
        if(empty($first_name)){ 
            $errorMsg .= 'Please enter your first name.<br/>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($last_name)){ 
            $errorMsg .= 'Please enter your last name.<br/>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($email)){ 
            $errorMsg .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($phone)){ 
            $errorMsg .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br/>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($address)){ 
            $errorMsg .= 'Please enter your address.<br/>'; 
        } 

        if(empty($errorMsg)){ 
            // Insert customer data in the database 
            $insertCust = $db->query("INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, email, phone, address) VALUES ('".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$email."', '".$phone."', '".$address."')"); 

            if($insertCust){ 
                $custID = $db->insert_id; 

                // Insert order info in the database 
                $insertOrder = $db->query("INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, grand_total, created, status) VALUES ($custID, '".$cart->total()."', NOW(), 'Pending')"); 

                if($insertOrder){ 
                    $orderID = $db->insert_id; 

                    // Retrieve cart items 
                    $cartItems = $cart->contents(); 

                    // Prepare SQL to insert order items 
                    $sql = ''; 
                    foreach($cartItems as $item){ 
                        $sql .= "INSERT INTO order_items (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('".$orderID."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['qty']."');"; 
                    } 

                    // Insert order items in the database 
                    $insertOrderItems = $db->multi_query($sql); 

                    if($insertOrderItems){ 
                        // Remove all items from cart 
                        $cart->destroy(); 

                        // Redirect to the status page 
                        $redirectLoc = 'orderSuccess.php?id='.$orderID; 
                    }else{ 
                        $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error'; 
                        $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.'; 
                    } 
                }else{ 
                    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error'; 
                    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.'; 
                } 
            }else{ 
                $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error'; 
                $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.'; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error'; 
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Please fill all the mandatory fields.<br>'.$errorMsg;  
        } 
        $_SESSION['sessData'] = $sessData; 
    } 
} 

// Redirect to the specific page 
header("Location: $redirectLoc"); 
exit();
```

Comment: Is the price 1 -> `price` and price 2 -> `pricet` (in the DB)?

Comment: Yes @VanTho, that's right.

Comment: You just need more input in your form, ex: `price_type`. Then read it by `$_REQUEST`. Using that varable to set the correct price to `$itemData` (just need one field `price` to store the selected price). Then save it into session.

Comment: @VanTho i'm at the start with php can you please help me by show me how to do what you mentioned? I will appreciate, thank you